# Download multiple files and/or folder from github using ansible

Tags: git, github, ansible

I have a github repo contain multiple applications and binaries. I just want to download a specific folder (eg: `application_1.2.0/`) from that repo which contains 1000's of files and subfolders.

And I want to write an ansible script to download it. I tried to make it `.zip` and upload to github so that I can download using `get_url` module in ansible from github. But, my bad it's more than 400 MB. GitHub is not accepting large files.

Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: This is called "sparse checkout" in Git vernacular. Ansible git module doesn't support it as of today (although you will see requests and discussions here and there in Google search results). You can use individual tasks to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're checking generated files (including, but not limited to, binaries) into your git repository, you're doing it wrong; git doesn't handle large files like that well, and the community considers that sort of thing as an anti-pattern.

There are a variety of other approaches, and which one makes sense will depend on your situation.  Common ones include:

- Storing the files on a filestore like Amazon S3
- Generating the files locally and deploying them directly using ansible (with the `copy` or `synchronize` modules)
- Generating the files as build artifacts in a CI system, and doing a "continuous deployment" push-based deploy within that system

Comment: I got your point, I know its wrong method of storing artefacts. But am not able to change the entire workflow now. I just looking for a workaround to fix this issue.

Comment: If you're ok with uploading a .zip to github and using `get_url`, then you should be ok with uploading a .zip to s3 and using `get_url`; those are the same amount of workflow change.